# Problems with skype on ubuntu 16.04.4 on AMD ryzen

Tags: skype

I have an issue with skype. I have installed it months ago, and I did have no problem on using it (I don't remember if it was on this machine or the old one).

I have ubuntu 16.04.4, and I am using an AMD ryzen 7 processor (I don't know if that is relevant at all).

However, when I log in, skype closes the sesion, and logsin automatically again, and loops into this process until it crashes and closes.

I have tried by removing skype using purge, and installing it again, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

try (re)moving the folder  ~/.config/skypeforlinux. If you don't care about your saved conversations maybe just delete and it will probably work